# Read cookies in silverlight

Tags: asp.net-mvc, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I have an ASP.NET MVC application. In this after user get Sign in .We set the a cookie for the user who logged in using FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, false). 
In other page we get the Cookies using the FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(userName]) .
This  cookie values as string is then set in the

```
Response.Cookies["username"].Value = cookiesvalue
```

We have .aspx page  in the same application that downloads silverlight application. Silverlight reads the cookies using the code

```
string[] cookies = HtmlPage.Document.Cookies.Split(';');
```

The problem is that once session expires in the application,silverlight cannot read the cookie value.

After the session expires we again set the cookies in headers using the

```
Response.Cookies["username"].Value = cookiesvalue
```

But still silverlight application cannot read this cookie .

Thanks in Advance
DNM

Comment: Explain what you are trying to accomplish. We can probably figure out a solution. Why are you trying to read the cookie?

Answer (score 0):

The authentication cookie (the one set with `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, false)`) is a special cookie. It is encrypted using the [machine key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx) on the server and it can only be manipulated by the server. Silverlight executes on the client side which explains why you cannot decrypt the username stored inside this cookie.

Just imagine for a moment that you could read and modify the value of this cookie on the client side : this would mean that you could impersonate any user.